# Multiple wars as single application

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, dependencies, war

I'm novice at EE development. I have war with some functionality and I want to add some new functionality. But I don't want put it in this war, so I need another one. Classes in this new war will depend on classes in first war. In java SE application I just split into two jars with proper dependency. How shoud I handle this in case of web application?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Create a library and add it to the war.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific. First war contains some web services, request filters, security context and so on. I want to create some new web services but put them in separate war.

Comment: A separate `war` is a separate web application. Is that what you want? A `war` contains its own libraries in `lib`, these libraries are just normal `jar`s. Simply create your dependencies as a `jar` and add them. Without more information this is the only use thing I can say.

Comment: No, I don't want separate web applications. I start thinking about using ear but I'm not sure I get what I want. I have EJBs exposed as restful web services. I've packaged them and all other stuff in war. Now I want to create another ejb and expose it as restful web service too, but I don't want to put it in existing war. What if I use two different ejb-jars for my EJBs? What should I put into ejb-jars and in war? Early I thought that if I use web services I should package them in war. Is there other way?